# Change value in textbox does not bind to the model

Tags: angular

I have an angular2 directive which is use to change word from `|`anything| to *special*:

html:

```
<textarea #contentInput id="content" special  [(ngModel)]="special" name="content" #content="ngModel"></textarea>
```

Angular:

```
let value = this.element.nativeElement.value;
let special = value.match(/|([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\+]+)|/g);
this.element.nativeElement.value = value.replace(special, "*special*");
```

> The value did change from |`anything| to *special*` on the textbox,
>   but it is not bind to the `ngModel`, but when I continue adding word
>   after the special word it will then bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you still need to dispatch the input event. This is what is listened for to determine when the value has changed

```
this.element.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/J8w4j4Ynpi99faMPLy2j?p=preview)